# the set of countable sets of Real numbers

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I would like to ask some hints towards the proof that The set of countable sets in $\mathbb{R}$ is equinumerous to the set $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Equinumerous to *what*?

Comment: I was still thinking the problem while typing. I didn't notice that I actually typed half of the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint:** $\Bbb{R^N\sim(N^N)^N\sim N^{N\times N}\sim N^N}$. Show that there exists a surjection from that set onto the set of countable subsets and use the axiom of choice to conclude there is an injection in the reverse direction.

Note that the axiom of choice has to be used, it is consistent that the axiom of choice fails and there is no bijection between the two sets (but there is still a surjection as above)!

Comment: About the last paragraph, see the opening of: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/47185/why-is-there-no-borel-function-mapping-every-countable-set-of-reals-outside-itsel/47306#47306