# Cardinality of a set of all subsets of $P(\omega)$ with cardinality $\omega$

Tags: set-theory

I am stuck on this one, do not know where to start. Any hint would be appreciated.

What is the cardinality of $[P(\omega)]^{\omega}$?
Is it equal to $|P(w)|$? How do I show that?

Comment: Or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1032886/show-that-using-the-axiom-of-choice-that-the-cardinality-of-the-sets-of-all-co/ or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184746/the-cardinality-of-the-set-of-countably-infinite-subsets-of-an-infinite-set/ can be used as duplicates also.

Comment: @AsafKaragila But these questions talk about the cardinality of the set of countably infinite subsets, i.e. $[\omega]^{\omega}$ but I don't see how it points me to finding $|[P(\omega)]^{\omega}|$.....

Comment: @AsafKaragila I can prove that $|P(\omega)| = 2^\omega$, but the question is whether $|[P(\omega)]^\omega| = 2^\omega$

Comment: Uhh, no. Look at them more closely. And read all the answers. Note I also suggested http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392978/the-set-of-countable-sets-of-real-numbers as an option.